# Perl Regular Expression not working for long_description

Tags: regex, string, perl

```
$text = <<"EOF";
{"product_id": "5I20SL43MWDD", "title": "Woodland Imports 2 Piece Ceramic Vase Set", "primary_shelf": [{"all_paths_str": "[[\"Home Page\",\"Home\",\"Decor\",\"Vases\"]]", "locale": "en_US", "value": "Vases", "path_id": "[\"0\",\"4044\",\"133012\",\"1043827\"]", "all_paths_id": "[[\"0\",\"4044\",\"133012\",\"1043827\"]]", "tag_source": "rule", "id": "1043827", "path_str": "[\"Home Page\",\"Home\",\"Decor\",\"Vases\"]"}], "alternate_shelves": "1043827", "last_updated_at": 1471417348, "primary_category_path": "0:4044:133012:1043827", "short_description": "Includes two vase. Gray and cream color palette. No assembly required. 5 in. L x 5 in. W x 12 in. H. Weight: 6 lbs.. Check out this Vase that will beautify your interiors. Can be kept assorted or separately depending upon your needs. For added beauty, you can also add flowers to this ceramic vase to flourish your interiors with fragrance. This vase will steal the spotlight and make you win appreciations from many. Besides, this vase can also be gifted to your beloved ones.", "item_id": "40966792", "attributes": {"package_quantity": ["1"], "assembled_product_width_raw_data": ["6.0"], "assembled_product_length_raw_data": ["6.0"], "is_always_show": ["N"], "assembled_product_height_raw_data": ["15.0", "15.0"], "color": ["Brown", "Brown"], "small_parts_warning_code": ["0"], "manufacturer_part_number": ["78681"], "primary_shelf_id": ["1043827"], "shape": ["Bud"], "manufacturer_suggested_retail_price": ["75.84"], "country_of_origin_components": ["Imported"], "assembled_product_length": ["6.0 IN", "6.0"], "category": ["Vases", "Vases"], "has_warranty": ["N"], "character_primary_category_path": ["Home/Decor/Vases"], "item_master_created_date": ["1414926519000"], "offer_lifecycle_status": ["ACTIVE"], "new": ["N"], "size": ["12\" H x 5\" W x 5\" D", "12\" H x 5\" W x 5\" D"], "type": ["Other Vases"], "brand": ["Woodland Imports", "Woodland Imports"], "all_shelves": ["Vases"], "is_preorder": ["N"], "primary_shelf": ["Vases"], "material": ["Ceramic", "Ceramic"], "assembled_product_width": ["6.0 IN", "6.0"], "california_residents_prop_65_warning_required": ["N"], "lifestage": ["Adult", "Adult"], "show_button_in": ["3"], "warranty_information": ["Warranty not available for this item"], "char_primary_category_path": ["Home/Decor/Vases"], "manufacturer": ["Woodland Imports"], "actual_color": ["Brown", "Brown"], "data_source": ["Catalog"], "product_type": ["Vases"], "size_raw_data": ["12"], "wupc": ["0083730378681"], "display_status": ["PUBLISHED"], "assembled_product_weight": ["7 Pounds"], "country_of_origin_assembly": ["Imported"], "assembled_product_height": ["15.0 IN", "15.0"], "warranty_length": ["Warranty not available for this item"], "model": ["78681"], "price_per_unit_quantity": ["1"]}, "long_description": "WLI15311<br /><strong>Features</strong><br /><li>Grey and cream color palette</li><li>Made of quality ceramic</li><li>Product Type: Floor vase</li><li>Shape: Bud</li><li>Color: Grey and cream</li><li>Primary Material: Ceramic</li> <br /><strong>Dimensions</strong><br />Size 15'' H x 6'' W x 6'' D<br /><li>Overall Height - Top to Bottom: 15''</li><li>Overall Width - Side to Side: 6''</li><li>Overall Depth - Front to Back: 6''</li><li>Overall Product Weight: 5.93 lbs</li><br />Size 12'' H x 5'' W x 5'' D<br /><li>Overall Height - Top to Bottom: 12''</li><li>Overall Width - Side to Side: 5''</li><li>Overall Depth - Front to Back: 5''</li><li>Overall Product Weight: 3.24 lbs</li>"}
EOF
```

This is my text, which is in json format. I want extract specific fields such as `short_description` and `long_description`

I am using this regex:

```
my ($title)=$text=~/"title"\s*:\s*"(.*?)"\s*,\s*"/is;**
my ($long_des)=$text=~/"long_description"\s*:\s*"(.*?)"\s*,\s*"/is;
```

Everything is coming correctly, but I don't know why the `long_description` regex is not working, I get an empty string. What do I need to do to remedy this?

Comment: If you are parsing JSON, why not `use JSON` and save yourself the hassle?

Comment: I dont know why this people downvote the question. I dont knew a better than only I asked the question. Thnx for answering and showing me better way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

I'll suggest taking a step back. It's nasty to hack JSON with regex, because of the contextual nature of JSON. Regex is not contextual, so is always a hacky solution.

Fortunately, perl has the `JSON` module that makes it simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my $json_str = q({"product_id": "5I20SL43MWDD", "title": "Woodland Imports 2 Piece Ceramic Vase Set", "primary_shelf": [{"all_paths_str": "[[\"Home Page\",\"Home\",\"Decor\",\"Vases\"]]", "locale": "en_US", "value": "Vases", "path_id": "[\"0\",\"4044\",\"133012\",\"1043827\"]", "all_paths_id": "[[\"0\",\"4044\",\"133012\",\"1043827\"]]", "tag_source": "rule", "id": "1043827", "path_str": "[\"Home Page\",\"Home\",\"Decor\",\"Vases\"]"}], "alternate_shelves": "1043827", "last_updated_at": 1471417348, "primary_category_path": "0:4044:133012:1043827", "short_description": "Includes two vase. Gray and cream color palette. No assembly required. 5 in. L x 5 in. W x 12 in. H. Weight: 6 lbs.. Check out this Vase that will beautify your interiors. Can be kept assorted or separately depending upon your needs. For added beauty, you can also add flowers to this ceramic vase to flourish your interiors with fragrance. This vase will steal the spotlight and make you win appreciations from many. Besides, this vase can also be gifted to your beloved ones.", "item_id": "40966792", "attributes": {"package_quantity": ["1"], "assembled_product_width_raw_data": ["6.0"], "assembled_product_length_raw_data": ["6.0"], "is_always_show": ["N"], "assembled_product_height_raw_data": ["15.0", "15.0"], "color": ["Brown", "Brown"], "small_parts_warning_code": ["0"], "manufacturer_part_number": ["78681"], "primary_shelf_id": ["1043827"], "shape": ["Bud"], "manufacturer_suggested_retail_price": ["75.84"], "country_of_origin_components": ["Imported"], "assembled_product_length": ["6.0 IN", "6.0"], "category": ["Vases", "Vases"], "has_warranty": ["N"], "character_primary_category_path": ["Home/Decor/Vases"], "item_master_created_date": ["1414926519000"], "offer_lifecycle_status": ["ACTIVE"], "new": ["N"], "size": ["12\" H x 5\" W x 5\" D", "12\" H x 5\" W x 5\" D"], "type": ["Other Vases"], "brand": ["Woodland Imports", "Woodland Imports"], "all_shelves": ["Vases"], "is_preorder": ["N"], "primary_shelf": ["Vases"], "material": ["Ceramic", "Ceramic"], "assembled_product_width": ["6.0 IN", "6.0"], "california_residents_prop_65_warning_required": ["N"], "lifestage": ["Adult", "Adult"], "show_button_in": ["3"], "warranty_information": ["Warranty not available for this item"], "char_primary_category_path": ["Home/Decor/Vases"], "manufacturer": ["Woodland Imports"], "actual_color": ["Brown", "Brown"], "data_source": ["Catalog"], "product_type": ["Vases"], "size_raw_data": ["12"], "wupc": ["0083730378681"], "display_status": ["PUBLISHED"], "assembled_product_weight": ["7 Pounds"], "country_of_origin_assembly": ["Imported"], "assembled_product_height": ["15.0 IN", "15.0"], "warranty_length": ["Warranty not available for this item"], "model": ["78681"], "price_per_unit_quantity": ["1"]}, "long_description": "WLI15311<br /><strong>Features</strong><br /><li>Grey and cream color palette</li><li>Made of quality ceramic</li><li>Product Type: Floor vase</li><li>Shape: Bud</li><li>Color: Grey and cream</li><li>Primary Material: Ceramic</li> <br /><strong>Dimensions</strong><br />Size 15'' H x 6'' W x 6'' D<br /><li>Overall Height - Top to Bottom: 15''</li><li>Overall Width - Side to Side: 6''</li><li>Overall Depth - Front to Back: 6''</li><li>Overall Product Weight: 5.93 lbs</li><br />Size 12'' H x 5'' W x 5'' D<br /><li>Overall Height - Top to Bottom: 12''</li><li>Overall Width - Side to Side: 5''</li><li>Overall Depth - Front to Back: 5''</li><li>Overall Product Weight: 3.24 lbs</li>"});
my $json = from_json($json_str);

print Dumper $json;

print "LONG:", $json ->{long_description},"\n";
```

Comment: Buddy I want to use it like this my $json_str = q($text); it is not working. I am using your solution only

Comment: It won't. `q()` is effectively a single quote (which I  use because of the quotes in the string). So it's trying to parse literally `'$text'`. Just use `my $json = from_json($text);` if it's already in a variable.